# How to access Java 9 Jshell on mac

Tags: macos, java-9

I have installed Jdk9 on MAC OSX and I have added the JDK path to  bash_profile. When I use jshell command from terminal, I am getting 'Command not found' error. I am able to get the correct version number when I type command `java -version`.

How do I access the jshell from terminal? do i need to include jdk 9 bin folder path in `bash_profile`?

Answer (score 4):

[Add JDK-9 bin in PATH environment variable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8smSx.png)

```
export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH
jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9.0.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro
jshell>
```

Comment: Please specify the reason for the downvotes. Did I miss something important? Is it a bad practice?

Comment: I think you got downvotes when your initial answer was just a link. Posting just a link is indeed bad practice.

Comment: I think it's a good answer, indeed, it solved my problem. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All you need to do is configure the ***`$JAVA_HOME/bin`*** in your *bash_profile* which can be done as :

[image]
and then confirm the java -version on your prompt.

[image]

***PS***: All other variables in `bash_profile` except `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` in the profile can be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**

Add the following to your `.bash_profile`

`export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`

After restarting your terminal, `jshell` should be a recognized command.

---

**Detailed Explanation**

Adding the directory `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin` to our `$PATH`,
allows us to be in any directory and
execute scripts/commands located in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`

`$PATH` is an environment variable

Executing `echo $PATH` in the terminal will print a colon-delimited list of directories stored in the `$PATH` environment variable.

For the following examples, `directory` = *whatever directory you want to add to your `$PATH`*

- `PATH=directory:$PATH` --> prepends a directory to the colon-delimited list
- whereas, `PATH=$PATH:directory` --> appends a directory to the colon-delimited list